# Macau/Hong Kong: Visa for going back and forth

Tags: visas, hong-kong, macau

As an EU citizen, Macau will give me a 90 day visa upon arrival.

Can I visit Hong Kong with that every other weekend or will leaving Macau void my visa?

Comment: I too feel completely nosey about, why you would be in Macau that long!! heh..

Comment: Perilously close to Rule 2... (http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rule-2-dont-judge-peoples-motivations-for-traveling)

Comment: @JoeBlow I didn't say I'm staying that long. They just give you 90 days whether you need them or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official website](http://www.fsm.gov.mo/psp/eng/EDoN.html), entry permits (visa-on-arrival) are only valid for 30 days and you don't need one as an EU citizen. What you'll get is 90 days of visa-free stay.

If you leave Macau, you will need to go through immigration when you come back and you could then theoretically be denied entry.

The same website specifies that

> 2  Non-residents will be refused entry to the Macao Special Administrative Region for the following reasons:
>
> (1) Attempting to evade the regulation on stay and residence and having frequent entries to the Macao Special Administrative Region within short intervals without appropriate justification;

In practice, staying in Hong Kong and travelling to Macau, I got a new entry stamp/authorization to stay each time very easily. I expect things to work the same the other way around but I don't know how often you can do that before raising suspicion.

Comment: I arrived in HK from Macau last week and ask the border official about this. "what prevents me from going back and forth between HK and Macau to get new 90 days every time". He said "nothing". I'm pretty sure there is no problem if the duration of your combined stays is less than 90 days.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can visit Hong Kong and re-enter.  To be exact, as an EU citizen you do not need a visa for Macau, [you will be granted a 90-day <s>entry permit</s> authorization to stay on arrival](http://www.fsm.gov.mo/psp/eng/EDoN.html#EDoN_VII).  Each individual authorization will end when you leave Macau, but you'll be granted a new one when you return.

Beware that, if you keep doing this, you may eventually be refused entry for

> (1)   Attempting to evade the regulation on stay and residence and
>   having frequent entries to the Macao Special Administrative Region
>   within short intervals without appropriate justification;

So you'd be advised to get a work/study/extended stay permit from Macau if you have reason to stay there longer, and I presume you do, because even a hardcore gambler would get a wee bit bored after 90 days!

Comment: Technically, I don't think you get an entry permit either. I am not particularly familiar with Macau law and I just learned about the rules but the website suggests you have to pay for an entry permit and I don't recall ever paying to enter Macau.

Comment: Good catch!  The official website doesn't really give the exemption-thing a name, but my passport stamp says *Autorizado a permanecer ate: (date)*, so I'm calling it an "authorization to stay".

Comment: I was wondering what it was called, as I renewed my passport recently and couldn't check that myself! +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived in Macao by plane on April 26th, as a German citizen I got I visa free stay until `25-07-2015` (90 days).

Yesterday (June 5th) I went on a day trip to Honk Kong, when returning to Macau I got a new `Arrival Card`, it states again:

> Permitted to remain until 25-07-2015

This indicates, that the original "visa" was not voided, and the 90 days did not get reset. I'm still on my original 90 days.

Which begs the question, when is it reset? I'm pretty sure last year when I left Macau and returned by plane I got new 90 days. But because there are no stamps for Hong Kong and Macau in my passport (you just get arrival cards) I can not verify that.

And No, I am not gambling here.